# Trie complexity using linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, tree, singly-linked-list, information-retrieval

I implemented a Trie using linked lists (not array as usual)
My TrieNode contains linked list as node (instead of limit the input type- english,number,etc...)
I wonder what is the current complexity of my Trie using linked list as nodes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a word *w* of length *l* is in the trie, you need to check at most *l* levels of the trie. In each layer, you need to check if the current node has a child with the letter you need next, by using linear search. The maximum number of child-nodes you need to iterate is the size of the alphabet you are using.

Therefore I think the answer is O(*l* * |*A*|), where *A* is the alphabet you are using, in case of lowercase latin letters *A*= a,b..,y,z;    so |*A*| = 26.

Comment: Nitpick, I think a better word than "length" would be "depth".

Comment: Yeah, "depth" makes sense for the trie. But with "length" I mean the length of the word you want to check. The depth of the trie can be 1000, but if the word has length 3, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: That's beside the point, though. Evaluating algorithmic complexity isn't about the number of operations in specific examples. It's about evaluating the average-case and/or worst-case scenarios. and Big-O specifically deals with worst-case. If the trie has a depth of 1000 and a word is 3 characters long, the number of actual operations is `x * y * z` (where x, y, and z is the number of letters that are in the first, second, and third node, respectively), but the trie's Big-O complexity is still `O(1000 * A)` because that's the worst-case scenario (a word 1000 characters long and full of Z's).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that I would use either linked list or an array* as the node storage for a trie, as either would make both search and insertion at each node be `O(n)`, thus the complexity for the trie overall `O(n * D)` approaching `O(A * D)`, where `A` and `D` are the alphabet length and trie depth, respectively.

Comparatively speaking, a hash map for each node strikes me as the least complex/most performant for a naive implementation of a trie as it would reduce complexity to search and insertion to `O(1)` per node and `O(D)` overall. The only additional complexity would be in resizing the map, but if space isn't a concern you could pre-size each map to have an initial capacity of `A`, eliminating the need to ever resize the maps dynamically.

<sup>**: This is based on using brute-force search and insertion for an array implementation. If you can create a static 1-1 mapping of characters to zero-based indices, you could achieve the same operational and space complexity as well as slightly better performance with an array than with a hash map.*</sup>